# Unable to run a MS Visual Studio due toCannot communicate with the debug host process. Failed to obtain child process active object

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am trying to run a Visual Studio package and keep getting this error before any step is initiated.

> ===================================
>
> Failed to start the project (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> ===================================
>
> Cannot communicate with the debug host process. Failed to obtain child
>   process active object.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger
>   iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32
>   flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow,
>   DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32
>   launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem,
>   DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32
>   launchOptions)
>          at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32
>   launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
>          at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32
>   launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

I have installed and run a [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool#overview) but still no luck.

I would appreciate any assistance. 
(using Visual Studio 2015, Version 14.03)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run a SSIS package in VS 2014.
I read somewhere that I should reinstall or repair SSDT.
I found the installer and I reinstalled SSDT.
Problem solved.
I hope this will be a good solution for you.